# Get difference between two spark dataframes having map datatype columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I Have two dataframes having map datatype columns. I'm trying to use the traditional except method to get the difference between the two dataframes, but I'm getting the below error.

```
scala> val outputDF = Seq(
     | (1, "Visa", 0, Map("Visa" -> 1)), 
     | (2, "MC", 2, Map("Visa" -> 1, "MC" -> 1)), 
     | (3, "Amex", 0, Map("Amex" -> 1)), 
     | (4, "Amex", 3, Map("Visa" -> 1, "MC" -> 1, "Amex" -> 1)), 
     | (5, "Amex", 4, Map("Visa" -> 2, "MC" -> 1, "Amex" -> 1)),
     | (6, "MC", 0, Map("MC" -> 1)), 
     | (7, "Visa", 5, Map("Visa" -> 3, "MC" -> 1, "Amex" -> 1)), 
     | (8, "Visa", 6, Map("Visa" -> 3, "MC" -> 2, "Amex" -> 1)), 
     | (9, "MC", 0, Map("MC" -> 1)),
     | (10, "MC", 2, Map("Amex" -> 1, "MC" -> 1))).toDF("person_id", "card_type", "number_of_cards", "card_type_details")
outputDF2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [person_id: int, card_type: string ... 2 more fields]


scala> val expectedOutputDF = Seq(
     | (1, "Visa", 0, Map("Visa" -> 1)), 
     | (2, "MC", 2, Map("Visa" -> 1, "MC" -> 1)), 
     | (3, "Amex", 0, Map("Amex" -> 1)), 
     | (4, "Amex", 3, Map("Visa" -> 1, "MC" -> 1, "Amex" -> 1)), 
     | (5, "Amex", 4, Map("Visa" -> 2, "MC" -> 1, "Amex" -> 1)),
     | (6, "MC", 0, Map("MC" -> 1)), 
     | (7, "Visa", 5, Map("Visa" -> 3, "MC" -> 1, "Amex" -> 1)), 
     | (8, "Visa", 6, Map("Visa" -> 3, "MC" -> 2, "Amex" -> 1)), 
     | (9, "MC", 0, Map("MC" -> 1)),
     | (10, "MC", 2, Map("Amex" -> 1, "MC" -> 1))).toDF("person_id", "card_type", "number_of_cards", "card_type_details")
expectedOutputDF2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [person_id: int, card_type: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> outputDF.printSchema
root
 |-- person_id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- card_type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- number_of_cards: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- card_type_details: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: integer (valueContainsNull = false)

scala> expectedOutputDF.printSchema
root
 |-- person_id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- card_type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- number_of_cards: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- card_type_details: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: integer (valueContainsNull = false)
```

I'm using the except method to see if there is difference between outputDF and expectedOutputDF.

```
scala> outputDF.except(expectedOutputDF)
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot have map type columns in DataFrame which calls set operations(intersect, except, etc.), but the type of column card_type_details is map<string,int>;;
Except false
:- Project [_1#886 AS person_id#891, _2#887 AS card_type#892, _3#888 AS number_of_cards#893, _4#889 AS card_type_details#894]
:  +- LocalRelation [_1#886, _2#887, _3#888, _4#889]
+- Project [_1#869 AS person_id#874, _2#870 AS card_type#875, _3#871 AS number_of_cards#876, _4#872 AS card_type_details#877]
   +- LocalRelation [_1#869, _2#870, _3#871, _4#872]

  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.failAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:42)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.failAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:95)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:364)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:85)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.checkAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:85)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:95)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:108)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:105)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.markInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:201)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:105)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:57)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:55)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:47)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:79)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withSetOperator(Dataset.scala:3419)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.except(Dataset.scala:1963)
  ... 51 elided
```

Is there a way to get the difference between two dataframes having column as Map datatype?

Answer (score 1):

**Below error says** set operations will not work if you have columns of data type `Map`.

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 
Cannot have map type columns in DataFrame which calls set operations(intersect, except, etc.), but the type of column card_type_details is map<string,int>;;
```

**Work around** for this issue is, Convert your `map type` column to `json` string and use `except` set operations and convert back to ``map type`from`json``` string.

Check below code.

```
outputDF
.withColumn("card_type_details",to_json($"card_type_details"))
.except(
    expectedOutputDF
    .withColumn("card_type_details",to_json($"card_type_details"))
)
.withColumn("card_type_details", from_json($"card_type_details",MapType(StringType,IntegerType)))
.show(false)
```